# Koschbasalt / Blaubasalt vs. Magic Traps

Tags: magic, traps, the-dark-eye

I hope there are even [Das Schwarze Auge/The Dark Eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_Schwarze_Auge) players around here...

Is it possible to neutralize magic traps (traps created by **applicatus** or similar spells, not **arcanovi**) using Koschbasalt and/or Blaubasalt?

I'm German, so I don't know if the names of these materials are different in the English version of DSA (TDE), and I have found no English page where I could look it up. If you know TDE but have no idea what Koschbasalt is: It's the material used to prevent imprisoned mages from using their spells, as it seems to absorb magic.

Answer (score 7):

#### Yes, to a degree

A precedent for this can be found in [Horte Magischen Wissens (Q7)](http://www.ulisses-spiele.de/produkte/100/horte-magischen-wissens/) (publisher link), on page 110 in the description of the School of Variable Forms of Mirham (Black Box).

There, for their Koschbasalt-Tower, it is noted that inside, not only does casting spells gets a +12 modifier, but also, that all Artifacts (no limit to Arcanovi here) lose 12 ZfP* of the bound Spell and cannot be activated if their ZfP* drops below one.

Thus, since this is pretty much one of the largest Koschbasalt Structures you can build, I think we can safely say: If the bound spell has a strength of 12 ZfP* or less, then it can be neutralized by a sufficient amount of Koschbasalt. If it is stronger than that, it will still go off, albeit severely weakened.

Comment: I assume that you found this in the German version of Q7, since I highly doubt the Q series has ever been translated.

Answer (score 5):

Using it the right way, it should be possible (even ones made with an arcanovi).
What does Koschbasalt?
Koschbasalt absorbs magic, so if you entomb a magic trap or at least cover the magic muzzle with a thick enough Koschbasalt wall, it should absorb the ignifaxius or whatever spell you want to fire.
But that means, you have to know that there a trap is, where the trap is and you have to cover it with Koschbasalt without triggering it.
But if you can do all that, I don't see why it shouldn't work.
But wearing a small rock of Koschbasalt wouldn't help.

Blaubasalt, the stronger concentrated essence of Koschbasalt, can absorb magic so strongly, that it can sometimes divert magic from its target to itself (I don't find the reference in my DSA books for that, but I'm sure that I've read it).
So wearing a rock of Blaubasalt could help (sometimes), but could also have it drawbacks. If you wear it, it could attract the ignifaxius, which should hit your partymember. And if it comes from behind and you have it on your breast, it could target the ignifaxius directly into your back. And the healing magic from your party mage also might not hit you ...